# Keybindings changed. C-h k has the wrong info. What did I do wrong?

Tags: key-bindings

I changed the keys for a slime function.

I changed `slime-eval-last-expression-in-repl` from **C-c C-j** to **C-x C-e**.

The mini buffer confirms the change:

[image]

But when I look at the help function, it says that `slime-eval-last-expression` instead of `slime-eval-last-expression-in-repl`

[image]

More importantly, the keys do not send the answer to the repl. What is the issue with the keybindings?

Update:

I changed my keybindings like this:

[image]

Comment: Please show how you changed the keybindings.

Comment: for sure. I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your keybinding in the global keymap, but the global keymap is overridden by the keymap for the major mode that you are in (generally referred to as the local keymap). As the help buffer states, this keymap is called `slime-mode-indirect-map`. As you have defined it, your key binding would only be active in modes other than `slime-mode`.

Normally you want to define mode–specific keys when that mode is first intitialized. This requires using a hook function. Try something like this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'slime-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key slime-mode-indirect-map
                (kbd "C-x C-e")
                'slime-eval-last-expression-in-repl)))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this Q&A is a dup, but I don't have time now to search for it.

Comment: Probably more than half of questions are.